# Use grepl and ifelse to add a new column

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which one columns contains websiteadresses.

```
 > head(df, 1)
                                                 title                     amount
1 Bureau (elektrisch verstellbaar) + bureaustoel ook apart         â‚¬Â 149,00    
                                                                                                                                         condition           city
1                         Zo goed als nieuw                            |                            Ophalen of Verzenden                             Heel Nederland
                                                                                                                                                                                  website_adress
1 http://www.marktplaats.nl/a/huis-en-inrichting/bureaus-en-bureaustoelen/a1040417850-bureau-elektrisch-verstellbaar-bureaustoel-ook-apart.html?c=d97e27c274e75147b4afd0f5eb58c81b&previousPage=lr
```

I want to filter out website addresses containing `admarkt`. I know how to grab them using:

```
data_met_admarket <- df[grepl("admarkt", df$website_adress),]
```

Thing I want to now however is add a label in the dataframe with 1 (has `admarkt`) in the link or 0 (has no `admarkt` in the link)

I try to do that like this:

```
df$contain_admarkt <-  ifelse(df[!grepl("admarket", df$website_adress),], 1, 0)
```

But then I get the following error:

> Error in ifelse(df[!grepl("admarket", df$website_adress), ], 1, 0) : 
>        (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'

Comment: post the output of `dput(df)`

Comment: remove `df[!` and `]` parts

Comment: Marktplaats aan het webscrapen, btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not like this:

```
df$contain_admarkt <- as.integer(grepl('admarkt',df$website_adress))
```